# Compile-time test for availability of UIApplication.shared?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have some shared code that needs to work in both iOS apps *and* app extensions, and needs to set `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` — but only if the code is used in an app.

In an app extension, `UIApplication.shared` gives this compile error:

```
'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead
```

That’s fine; I don’t *want* to use it in the app extension. However, I’m unable to find a way to disable that code at compile time. Sadly, `if #available` doesn’t seem to do the trick; it shuts off the code path, but the compiler still doesn’t like it:

```
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 0, *) {
    print("This is an extension")
} else {
    print("This is an app")
    print(UIApplication.shared)  // Unreachable in extension, but still doesn’t compile
}
```

I don’t see any `#if` check that handles this.

Is there any way in Swift to conditionally compile the code that requires `UIApplication.shared`?

Comment: You'll need to refactor your code so any code using any API not allowed in an extension isn't targeted to the extension.

Comment: A CocoaPod designed to serve both apps and extensions can’t do that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @fruitcoder Nope, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to avoid explicit usage of `UIApplication.shared` and use Objective-C selector wrap instead.

Here is an extension that might help (based on https://github.com/ephread/Instructions/issues/21)

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var safeShared: UIApplication? {
        guard UIApplication.responds(to: Selector(("sharedApplication"))) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let unmanagedSharedApplication = UIApplication.perform(Selector(("sharedApplication"))) else {
            return nil
        }

        return unmanagedSharedApplication.takeRetainedValue() as? UIApplication
    }
}
```

Usage

```
if let app = UIApplication.safeShared {
    result = app.applicationState == .active
}
```

Happy Coding ‍